# Login timed out after 60 seconds

Tags: server, 10.04, login, timeout

Booting server Ubuntu 10.04, no GUI installed, only console, inputing correct username, receiving "Login timed out after 60 seconds.". after around a minute with no password prompt.

Trying with username "root", receiving password prompt, inputing correct password, receiving "Login timed out after 60 seconds.", trying incorrect password, also receiving "Login timed out after 60 seconds.". Trying several times, always the same output.

No upgrades/updates were done. Any ideas what is possibly going on? I have very little sysadmin skills.

Comment: same happened to me now on 16.04 in a VirtualBox VM. Can't do anything... I issued an ACPI Shutdown, but it's not even shutting down...

Answer (score 1):

Something (app, DB, util) is consuming all of your proc table on boot.  I suggest going in single user mode and turning off all non-root process using `chkconfig` and then reboot.

Once you are in on the console, you can start things manually one at a time and determine which process is killing your server.  You will notice the load average go up by using `top` after you start each process in `/etc/init.d`.